# Android : HTTP Post Issue

Tags: android

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String data = "valid SOAP REquest";
```

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("valid url");
        Log.d("inside", "created http post");
        try {
              ByteArrayInputStream baos = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());

```
        Log.d("inside", "firing request...");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
        Log.d("inside", "request sent" + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

Always, I get the status code as 405. I tried request queue as well.. sneding the byte array as part of the request queue, still the same issue.

Comment: What content type did you have to set?

Answer (score 0):

Who is hosting your server-side request ?
A 405 is typically because a srvice provider will not allow a POST.
[Look here for what 405 is](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html). and a couple of solutions.

Comment: Issue was with the content type :(. It got resolved now. Thanks for all your help